# windows is undefined while using react-sweet-state with nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am getting a `windows is undefined` error while using `react-sweet-state` with `nextjs`.
I have seen similar nextjs issues and the recommended solution was to use a rendering condition `typeof window === undefined`. I cannot use that rendering condition because I need the app to load even when the window is undefined.
Is there any other way to resolve the issue ?

Edit: I have added some code here which may help

pages/article/[id].js

```js
const Article = () => {

  //                         here is where i get the 'windows is undefined' error
  const [{ article }, { fetchArticleData }] = useArticleStore();
  
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta property="og:title" name="og:title" content={article.title} />
        <meta property="og:description" name="og:description" content={article.desc} />
      </Head>
      <article>
        <h1>{ article.title }</h1>
        <p 
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: article.content }}
        ></p>
    </>
  )
 }
```

pages/_app.js

```js
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "../styles/globals.scss";

import Layout from "../layout";

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div suppressHydrationWarning>
        {typeof window === "undefined" ? null : <Component {...pageProps} />}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: You can use the condition for only the lines you want to use the window object

Comment: _"I need the app to load even when the window is undefined"_ why? And how are you using the library. From their readme, it appears that it is simply for state management. Why does a react state management library has dependency on the `window` object in the first place? This doesn't sound right. Show us some code. Also, that's `typeof window === 'undefined'`, but most probably you don't need it. I am guessing you are assigning some state that needs `window.something`. You probably need to set it inside a `useEffect` hook. But we can't tell for sure without looking at your code first.

Comment: @brc-dd I am not using window for any of my states but the state management package is throwing error. Actually I want to load the app even when the window is undefined because in a url preview the window is undefined, but I need the app to load for fetching the data to be updated to the meta tags. 

And also the error is at the location where i import my actions and states. So it can't be put in a ```useEffect```

Comment: @AliAtaf Im not using window object anywhere. Its the package ```react-sweet-state``` which uses it. The error is at the line where I import the store. As you know we can't add conditions to import statements

Comment: @juliomalves No, it didn't

Comment: Can you show us the code for `useArticleStore`?